# Mining Nanopool almost without shares?

Tags: ethereum-classic, mining-pools, shares

I'm using nanopool to mine ethereum classic, but Nanopool tells me that my device is offline because it doesn't get any shares

This is my account :

https://etc.nanopool.org/account/0x710c74cb31e56307be0cb68cd345eb90fde5e0a3

What is the problem, and how can I get shares quickly ?

OS: windows
GPU: MSI RX 580 Armor 8GB OC 
Software: Claymore
Internet speed: 80mbps download - 5mbps upload